# Does the function $z+\frac{1}{z}$, $z\in \mathbb{C}$, have real-world applications?

Tags: complex-analysis

The function

$$z+\frac{1}{z}$$

seems to play a role in complex analysis.

However, does it have any applications besides what can be deduced in pure mathematics?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform

Answer (score 6):

Let $z = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} x}$. Then
$$
\cos(x) = \dfrac{z + \frac{1}{z}}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is called the Joukowski transform and it is used in airfoil design.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform